# How to use Python Pandas to sort data frame to match files and invoice amounts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with 4 columns. I need column 1 and 2 (new_df_1 and bill_df_1) to not change. I want to sort (new_File_Number_Data  new_invoice_total) to match column 1 and 2 and if there is no match, match it with missing.

```
    new_df_1    bill_df_1   new_File_Number_Data    new_invoice_total
0   1-08912-000218-033  25.0    1-08915-000041-054  134.50
1   1-08915-000041-054  163.0   001-0464-01589-061  148.50
2   001-0464-01589-061  166.7   004-3001-00080-532  54.00
3   004-3001-00080-532  74.0    missing             missing
```

[easier to look at Python Data Frame pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8Vaj.png)

Comment: The two commands in your picture are relevant, you should paste them as text. In short, you're making your job harder. Just use the original gs_df and occ_df, otherwise you'll just have to split them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't sort only some columns of a dataframe and not others. It sounds like you need to separate the columns into two different dataframes and then merge them so that they are matched as you want. You can then fill the missing values with the string 'missing'. For example:

```
df1 = df[['new_df_1', 'bill_df_1']]
df2 = df[['new_File_Number_Data', 'new_invoice_total']]

new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on='new_df_1', right_on='new_File_Number_Data').fillna('missing')
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked. I appreciate it. I am new to Pandas

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I was able to help. Remember to mark the question as answered so that others can find it.